Deny running a specific command in python virtual environment
Premise: I have created a python wrapper (let's call the wrapper pycomd) around a command (let's call the command comd).
Requirement: I want to deny the user from running comd whenever they run my command (pycomd) in a virtual environment where pycomd is installed. But I want my program (pycomd) to be able to call comd as my command is just a wrapper around comd and only performs cetain operations before and after running comd.
Attempt: I created pycomd project using a pyproject.toml file.
I supplied comd as a script to pyproject.toml file as such:
[project.scripts]
# certain other scripts
comd = "pycomd.comd.sup_comd:suppress_comd"

This is the content of pycomd/comd/sup_comd.py file:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding=utf-8
import sys

def suppress_comd():
    sys.exit("Error: Cannot run comd command directly in pycomd environment")

This approach actively suppresses the call to comd whenever user runs it from an virtual envirmonent where pycomd is installed. Thus a terminal call to comd errs as such:
(.venv) [suhas@pc] ~/: comd
(.venv) [suhas@pc] ~/: Error: Cannot run comd command directly in pycomd environment
(.venv) [suhas@pc] ~/: echo $?
(.venv) [suhas@pc] ~/: 1

pycomd calls comd as such:
comd_call = ["comd", "call", *args]
ret = subprocess.run(comd_call,
                    # stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  # no need to capture stdout from subcommand, let it print
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, check=True)

Accomplishment: This approach denies user/terminal from calling comd.
Issue: This approach also denies pycmd from calling comd and I want pycomd to be able to call comd.
Request: Is there a better way to do this?
It seems that this is quite a common thing when someone makes a wrapper on a command but I was not able to find much information on this.

Allow it to run when you pass in a super-secret argument?

Umm, can be done, but what if the user somehow enters that argument?
(I know this will be quite rare, more rare if the super-secret argument is many characters long, but still seems more of a hack or a hot-fix solution).

Well, there is no good way to completely prevent the user from running the wrapped command entirely whilst allowing your code to call it on their behalf (short of building some sort of privileged service, which seems like severe overkill here). If you don't like the secret command-line argument, perhaps an environment variable or the presence of a hidden file would work (though the latter is much less elegant and robust).

Environment variable approach seems fine.

One more approach seems fine. Path to comd can be stored in a local config file and that path can be used to run comd instead of directly calling comd from terminal.
This approach even lets the user choose in future about which comd version they'd like to run if they have two or more versions of comd installed.
